# jquery mobile "taphold" on map

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, openlayers

I am creating a web-based app using jquery mobile, based on openlayers API. I am having trouble with firing "taphold" event on map. Can you tell me how can i fire the taphold event over a map. I have tried many examples of taphold, but unfortunately failed.

here is my code:

```
$('#map').bind('taphold', function(e){
var position = map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy);
alert(position);
```

});

Comment: check this, might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264853/using-longclick-taphold-with-google-maps-in-jquery-mobile

Comment: thanks for quick comment, I have already tried this, actually i am using openlayers API to put OSM and the problem is that it is not working with openlayers.

Answer (score 0):

Once you succeed you will notice that the tap event is also fired which you may not want. More here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/3803. It seems that with jQM 1.4 there will be an option to prevent tap from firing.

I realize this is not an answer but I see absolutely no possibility to place a comment. Which is very weird because 1. other comments have been made (how?) and 2. after saving this answer there is an "add comment" link to comment this answer...

Comment: You need 50 reputation to comment on other people's posts. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment